# White logos with transparent backgrounds are problematic

Tags: bug, chat, design, user-interface, logo

A year ago, [I posted this question (s/question/bug report) to UX Meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1714/53472).

Today, I checked in to see if the issue has been fixed (it hasn't), and I've found that at least one other site (Pro Webmasters) suffers this same dilemma.

The problem is the way that Stack Exchange chat one-boxes links to network sites.  If you post a link to the main site, it grabs that site's logo.

For example, when you paste `meta.stackexchange.com` into chat, you get a message that looks like this:

[image]

That gets one-boxed in place of the link. It's pretty nice.

But some of the network sites have white text (and possible even white logo) on a transparent background. So against the white background of chat, simply nothing at all appears.

For the original example of UX:

[image]

And here's a look at what Pro Webmasters looks like:

[image]

We can at least see the logo, but the white, borderless text is lost.  For comparison sake, here's the blue background when the person who sent the message is viewing it:

[image]

I'm not certain what the easiest solution would be, and I'm sure there are other network sites that probably suffer the same problem.

At a minimum, I would suggest that any future site designs keep this in mind and at least put a border around the text.

The growing list:

- [image]

Comment: Not all chat rooms use a white background (Mos Eisley, for one), so not using white isn't the answer.  I think a border is the solution here.